# paypal, let customer pay half of total price

Tags: php, paypal

I have an item that costs $500 for example. I wanna let users be able to make partial payments, for example I wanna let them pay 50% of that amount ($250) and the other half is due after a certain number of time (like 3 weeks for example). How do I do that in Paypal?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: that's business logic you handle in your code, paypal ust takes what ever value you parse it

Comment: You can always setup an ending [subscription button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/) or [installment button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/installment_buttons/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the PayPal API has installment payments built into it (aside from PayPal Credit), so I would recommend setting up a simple web application and database with a PayPal IPN endpoint to collect details on payments made into your account: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/